# Define width of last column in order that table fits text width

Tags: tables, column-width

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lcp{5cm}}
  Category & Data & Explanation       \\
  AA       & 1.2  & \lipsum[1][1-3]
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

with the output:

[image]

I would like to adjust the size of the last column so that the table fits the size of the text width. I tried using `p{\fill}` but it didn't work.

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lcX}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%<-------------only for check, remove in finals
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lcX}
  Category & Data & Explanation       \\
  AA       & 1.2  & \lipsum[1][1-3]
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```